# Is there any native way of detecting the file extension?

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework

At the moment, I am doing the following, which is not what I am looking for. I just want to be able to detect the file extension, and depending on that, either copy it to the server, or reject it.

```
    MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
    FileInputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(file);
    String mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);

    InputStream is2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    String content = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is2);

    System.out.println(mimeType);
    System.out.println(content);
```

I get the mimetype, but again, thats not what I want. `URL.guessContentFromStream()` always returns null.

Does play have a native way to read the file extension? What other solutions are there?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to know the mime type or the file extension? If file extension what is wrong with `"filename.txt".substring("filename.txt".lastIndexOf('.'))` ?

Comment: @RosdiKasim Could you post this as an answer, so I could accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting file extension is pretty trivial, here is what I normally do:

```
String filename = "a long.filename.ext";
String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `FileTypeDetector` from package `java.nio.file.spi`

**See this link for more details:**

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html

**/////Edited//////**

Try `FileNameExtensionFilter`

**See this link:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html

Comment: I dont have such a package. The documentation says it exists after v1.7. I use v1.6.